# Java: VTD-XML 2.10: How to: get the attribute val without namespace aware?

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I am using VTD-XML to merge my xml files which have greater than 800MB
file size (high possibility to reach 2GB).
I've read the documentation that can support 2GB if namespace aware is
set to false.
With that said, how can I use properly the selecXPath() evalXPath() and
getAttrVal() etc.. ?
Because I am receiving a namespace error but can run properly if I
switch to namespace aware true.

```
VTDNav gmlNav = null;
//if(! gen.parseFile(gmlFile, true)) return;
if(! gen.parseFile(gmlFile, false)) return;
gmlNav = gen.getNav();

AutoPilot gmlAutoPilot = new AutoPilot(gmlNav);
//gmlAutoPilot.declareXPathNameSpace("xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
//gmlAutoPilot.declareXPathNameSpace("gml","http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2");

//sourceAutoPilot.selectXPath("//*[gml:id='123' or gml:id='456']");
sourceAutoPilot.selectXPath("//*[id='123' or id='456']");
while (sourceAutoPilot.evalXPath() != -1) {
    //String gmlId = sourceNav.toString(sourceNav.getAttrVal("gml:id"));
    String gmlId = sourceNav.toString(sourceNav.getAttrVal("id"));
}
```

note:the commented codes are the namespace aware true.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: did I answer your question via vtd-xml-users mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use extended VTD-XML which doesn't have the limitation of the standard vtd-xml in terms of namespace. In standard vtd-xml, if the namespace awareness is turned on, the maximum document size is 1GB.